# wordpress modal ajax load php file on click

Tags: ajax, wordpress, modal-dialog

hi if any one can suggest how to load a my custom php file in my wordpress theme .i want to load the php file only when the modal button is click

```
 var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

> `<class id="myBtn"><p>load modal</p>  </class>`

```
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">


   please wait while content loads .....


  <?php get_template_part( 'content-modal.php' ); ?>

     </div>
      </div> </div>
```

> any suggestions would be most appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to get information from server, after page loaded and myBtn is clicked. If so you cannot get information or php code from server unless you call an ajax function or send request(like GET/POST) which causes reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load new data without reloading current page then use AJAX

Ajax will send request to specified file `url` and will get contents of file in `success function`

Add the following code:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  $.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:'content-modal.php',
  success: function (data){//received content
  $(".modal-body").empty();
  $(".modal-body").append(data);
  }
  });
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
   please wait while content loads .....
     </div>
      </div> </div>
```

Comment: thank for your assistance however it does not retrieve the content.php file                                        my trigger button                                                                                                       
         <class id="myBtn"><p>load modal</p>  </class>